# Using immediate window to test a variable with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim Column1 As String
Column1 = ActiveCell.Column
```

I know this is a basic question, but when I type in ?Column1 into the immediate window it comes up blank. I want it to tell me the value of what Column1 is, what is the quickest way to do that /  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `Stop` after those two lines and run your code.  You need to be in break mode to do what you want.  FYI `Column` should go into a `Long`, not `String`

Comment: Or just `Debug.Print Column1` (after changing `String` to `Long` of course).

Comment: And if you want to go beyond just finding the value, use [Watch window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/watch-window).

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work